# RecyclerView notifyItemInserted IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

i am porting my adapter into `RecyclerView.Adapter`

**what i want to achieve:**
when the user scrolls down near the end i want to start fetch data, i also want to add i ProgressBar view at the end to let the user know more data is coming.

**the way i implemented this in my BaseAdapter:** on `getView` in the view requested in near the end, i would start fetching more data, call notifyDataSetChanged (to get the ProgressBar view to show) and only then return the view needed for`getView`.

**what i tried doing in RecyclerView.Adapter:** i tried to do the same thing basically, this time in the method `onBindViewHolder`,

but if i try and call `notifyItemInserted` inside this method i get the following exception:

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
```

**what i tried:** i noticed that `onBindViewHolder` gets called from `onLayoutChildren` from `LayoutManager`, i tried overriding it and calling `notifyItemInserted` after its `super` but i got the same exception

how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: use LinearLayoutManager for this job

Comment: could you write an example?, i couldn't do this without getting this exception

Comment: override onScrollStateChanged,  here use findLastVisibleItemPosition to check you are at the bottom and update your Adapter

Comment: btw you dond need to subclass LinearLayoutManager,  the same you can do with RecyclrView.OnScrollListener

Comment: i tried that and this works, but the update only start when the user finished the scroll and i don't get that seamless scrolling like i had before RecyclerView

Comment: so use `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrolled`, instead of `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged`

Comment: did RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrolled work?

Comment: it sorta worked, i ended up getting another exception which i am not sure is related, i ended up ditching RecyclerView because i believe the current implementation of StaggeredGridViewLayout is not very stable at the moment

Answer (score 46):

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        handler.post(r);
```

My sample code where I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); from Activity

Comment: Omg that helped me so much. But does this process require much capacity or is it inefficient?

Comment: I don't know that much.

Comment: this works, thanks. I shouldn't have upgraded to the new support library.

Comment: but it does not let me create handler object due to its abstraction :(

Comment: @AbdulWaheed please have a look at my code snippet below for your case.

Comment: Ahh find out the reason.I was importing wrong class

Comment: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true  =(

Answer (score 22):

It's also worth noting the JavaDoc on the `RecyclerView.isComputingLayout()` method that triggers this exception :

```
/**
 * Returns whether RecyclerView is currently computing a layout.
 * <p>
 * If this method returns true, it means that RecyclerView is in a lockdown state and any
 * attempt to update adapter contents will result in an exception because adapter contents
 * cannot be changed while RecyclerView is trying to compute the layout.
 * <p>
 * It is very unlikely that your code will be running during this state as it is
 * called by the framework when a layout traversal happens or RecyclerView starts to scroll
 * in response to system events (touch, accessibility etc).
 * <p>
 * This case may happen if you have some custom logic to change adapter contents in
 * response to a View callback (e.g. focus change callback) which might be triggered during a
 * layout calculation. In these cases, you should just postpone the change using a Handler or a
 * similar mechanism.
 *
 * @return <code>true</code> if RecyclerView is currently computing a layout, <code>false</code>
 *         otherwise
 */
public boolean isComputingLayout() {
    return mLayoutOrScrollCounter > 0;
}
```

The salient phrase being :

> In these cases, you should just postpone the change using a Handler or a
>   similar mechanism.

In my case, I was modifying the adapter contents from another thread, which was (occasionally) causing a collision. Shifting the update to a Handler on the UI thread naturally solves this.

Answer (score 9):

Using a `Handler` for adding items and calling `notify...()` from this `Handler` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That's the right answer, you cannot change item while it is setting (with calling onBindViewHolder). In that case you have to call notifyItemInserted at the end of current loop by calling Handler.post()

Answer (score 6):

**Neat** and **easy** way:

```
  recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Explanation: You use your `RecyclerView` instance and inside the post method a new `Runnable` added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread. This is a limit for Android to access the UI thread from background (e.g. inside a method which will be run in a background thread).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
if (!recyclerView.isComputingLayout()) {
        recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
private void notifyItemInsertedEx(final int position) {
    try {
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                notifyItemInserted(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```